# Get childNode attributes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the attributes of an element's children ... something like this:

```
<div id="mydivs">
  <div name="mydiv1" name="format1">

  </div>
  <div name="mydiv2" format="format2">

  </div>
</div>


var parent = document.getElementById('mydivs');

var children = parent.childNodes;

for (let child of children) {
  console.log(child)
  console.log(child.attributes)
}
```

`child.atrribute` returns `undefined`

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8tdac5fn/

Edit: Another option would be to use `children` instead of `childNodes`

```
var parent = document.getElementById('mydivs');
var children = parent.children;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parent.childNodes` will include text nodes and that is why you are getting `undefined`, so you can first check if `nodeType` is 1 which is `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`.

Then you could use spread syntax in array to create array of attribute nodes so you can use `forEach` loop.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('mydivs');
var children = parent.childNodes;

for (let child of children) {
  if (child.nodeType === 1) {
    [...child.attributes].forEach(({name,value}) => {
      console.log(`${name} - ${value}`);
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mydivs">
  <div name="mydiv1" name="format1"></div>
  <div name="mydiv2" format="format2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children to begin with …